# Cannot access remotely MySql docker image on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a node/express API connected to a mysql db on an EC2 instance but I have been stuck on this for weeks now so I hope I'll get some help.

I pulled the docker image for Mysql on my EC2 instance like this:

`sudo docker run --detach --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql`

and I got this response:

`[System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

I also added the TCP / port:3306 in the security groups of the AWS console.

Then I tried to connect to my db on Sequel Pro, with my instance's IPv4 as host, "root" as username and port 3306, it didn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your security group om the ec2 instance allow for incoming connections on port 3306?

Comment: @Fizk yes I added an incoming rule of type Mysql/Aurora, TCP protocole, and 3306 port

Comment: Ok, great - Have you tried to publish the port with -p 3306:3306 ?

Comment: @Fizk I just tried it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, if you ssh into the ec2 instance, can you connect directly to the DB? "mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p" and the enter the password when promoter for it.

Comment: @Fizk it says mysql: command not found. Is it because I pulled the image from docker instead of installing mysql directly on the instance?

Comment: Yes, you need to install a MySQL client. My suspesion is that root access to the DB is only available through localhost and that you need to create a user that can connect from anywhere.

Comment: never allow access directly to your database, that is a huge security risk look for REST and a server side programming language

Comment: @Fizk thank you, i managed to connect remotely to the db with sequel pro.

Comment: @nbk Alright, i'll read about it tomorrow. What alternative do you suggest ?

Comment: php python nodejs it doesn't matter, only the web server will deliver the data, the technique is irrelevant. it can also run in the docker.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check the following steps: always from inside to outside

- Does the DB allowing connections from public IPs? See the use of % in host.

```
SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;
```

- Are you publishing the port 3306 in the docker
- Are you publishing the port 3306 in your instance

You can use telnet(`telnet host 3306`)  by to easy test it out, or nmap to discover open ports. Always start from the closes point and go away step by step.
Also it's a good idea test it with a mysql client.

Also before publish the mysql administration port, please review the security issues that this creates. You are surely gonna be brute force attacked, so, at least add a firewall rule that limit the access only to your IP address or others IPS methods